# Iterating through a list of a class

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have made a list of "Teams" from a text file. I am just unable to iterate through it

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TXT1.txt"))
{
    using(JsonReader jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        JsonSerializer js = new JsonSerializer();
        List<Teams> leagueTeams = js.Deserialize<List<Teams>>(jr);
    }
}
```

This is where the list is made. I tried to do a `foreach` loop here:

```
foreach (var item in LeagueTeams)
{

}
```

But there is an error with the `LeagueTeams` in the `foreach` saying

> it doesn't exist in that context.

Whole piece of code:

```
class Teams
{
    public string name;
    public int GoalDiff;
    public int POints;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TXT1.txt"))
        {
            using(JsonReader jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                JsonSerializer js = new JsonSerializer();
                List<Teams> leagueTeams = js.Deserialize<List<Teams>>(jr);
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in LeagueTeams)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: declare ``List<Teams> leagueTeams`` before the first using.

Comment: **L**eagueTeams in the foreach != `leagueTeams` without the capitalised first letter.

Comment: And [Compiler Error CS0103](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0103) , we must have a master dupe for that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access the `leagueTeams` outside the scope of it's declaration, that's why you are getting this error. So what you need is moving the declaration of `List<Teams> leagueTeams` before your `using` statement:

```
List<Teams> leagueTeams = new List<Teams>();
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TXT1.txt"))
{
   ....
   ....
   leagueTeams = js.Deserialize<List<Teams>>(jr);
```

Also you need to fix the variable's name in your `foreach` loop. Based on what you've declared, the `LeagueTeams` is incorrect and it should be `leagueTeams`:

```
foreach (var item in leagueTeams)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to iterate over `LeagueTeams` class probably, what you probably want to do is to iterate over the list you have just created by deserializing (parsing) your file.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Teams> leagueTeams = new List<Teams>();
        using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TXT1.txt"))
        {
            using(JsonReader jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                JsonSerializer js = new JsonSerializer();
                leagueTeams = js.Deserialize<List<Teams>>(jr);
            }
        }

        foreach (var team in leagueTeams)
        {
            // access each team by 'team' variable
        }

        // another way using LINQ
        leagueTeams.ForEach(team => 
        {
            // access each team by 'team' variable
        });
    }
}
```